# Knockout template : how to provide function parameter/s for looped object, also function call 'is not defined'

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, knockoutjs

I am trying to edit an **existing** payment method module template:

This is a looped object `option` (which is information about the *current loop iteration payment method).*

The original template loop:

```
<ul class="types">
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: JSON.parse(getPaymentTypesList()), as: 'option' } -->
    <li class="option-type" onclick="jQuery(this).find('input[name=payment-type]').prop('checked', true);">
        <input class="paygate-payment-type" data-bind="attr: {'value': option.value}" name="payment-type"
            type="radio" />
        <label class="label">
            <span class="payment-type-label">
                <!-- ko i18n: option.label -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <span class="payment-type-label-img">
                <img alt="" class="payment-type-label-img" data-bind="attr: {'src': option.image}" />
            </span>
        </label>

    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

I want to use parameters to a custom function I created in the `.js` knockout object file; using the `option` payment method provided in the template already, see sample `visible` bind to the option.

```
<p class="payment-type-extra-description" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethod(option, 'BT')">
    <span class="payment-type-extra-description-span">- I just want to show this specific paragraph using 'visible' when the option object is the specified 'payment method' value.</span>
</p>
```

```
    isPaymentMethod: function (methodValue, paymentMethod) {
        if (paymentMethod && methodValue) {
          return paymentMethod == methodValue.value
        }
        return false
    },
```

I think I have two issues here which relate to this question, but without both resolved I can't solve the problem.

- I don't know how to provide arguments in the loop (using `option`)
- `isPaymentMethod is not defined`, **but only when inside the loop**; if I call the `isPaymentMethod` on an element *outside the loop*; this function is called without error (but I don't have arguments available since it is not inside the loop)

Error supplied in console; but as pointed out *only when inside the loop*

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return (paymentTypesEnabled() != 0) }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return { data:JSON.parse(getPaymentTypesList()),as:'option'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "visible: function(){return isPaymentMethod() }"
Message: isPaymentMethod is not defined
```

- How do I provide parameters to a function inside the loop?
- How do I get the loop to 'recognize' the `isPaymentMethod` function; because outside the loop the `visible: isPaymentMethod()` is called (but have not provided arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being completely confused about the issue this morning, I tried to research about the **context of the knockout objects**, as it appeared to me I need to find out why the function didn't work inside the loop.

I then found the `_Binding Context_` article and this relevant information:

```
$parent

This is the view model object in the parent context, the one immeditely outside the current context. In the root context, this is undefined


$parentContext

This refers to the binding context object at the parent level. This is different from $parent, which refers to the data (not binding context) at the parent level.
```

Only after reading `$parentContext` and then `$parent` I understood the context better.

The function implementation was already correct, so all I needed was to figure out how to call the function from the parent context:

```
<p class="payment-type-extra-description" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethod(option, 'BT')">
```

**should become**

```
<p class="payment-type-extra-description" data-bind="visible: $parent.isPaymentMethod(option, 'BT')">
```

For a long time I thought that the parameters I gave caused the `isPaymentMethod` function signature not to be 'recognized' by Knockout in the loop, wasting time on trying to solve the wrong issue (figuring out 'syntax' for `option` as argument).

Only after investigating the context **(binding context in knockout)** is when I realised the issue is easy to resolve.